# document.getelementbyid() of input return undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

document.getelementbyid() of input return undefined value idk why 
I don't gete any errors or something just the table get stocked with value undefined , the function get called when I submit the button

```
function Enregistrer(){
  //----------TERMINER LA FONCTION ICI----------------
  var id   =document.getElementById('field-id').Value ;
  var Lnom = document.getElementById('field-nom').Value;
  var pers = document.getElementById('field-prenom').Value;
  var mail = document.getElementById("field-mail").Value;
   alert( document.getElementById("field-mail").Value);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO myTable (nom,prenom,email) VALUES (?,?,?)',[Lnom,pers,mail]);

  });

    lister();
    vider();
    inputSHOW(false);


}
```

Comment: .Value !== .value

Answer (score -1):

An HTMLInputElement doesn't have a `Value` property. It does have a `value` property. Case does matter.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: Please don’t encourage trivial typo questions, as those are off-topic.

Comment: @Xufox gruesome.